# Counting sort output problem: read access violation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to work on the counting sort algorithm. The program runs when use the debugger but the problem is what it outputs. The output values are -842150451 in visual studio. I'm not sure why I'm getting that values. I'm also getting this pop up to:

> "Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
>   **C** was 0x34B6F822. occurred"

What am I doing wrong?

this is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector> 


using namespace std;

void count(int A[], int B[], int k, int n) {


int i;
int j;

int* C = new int[k];


for (i = 0; i < k+1; i++) {
    C[i] = 0;
}

for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    C[A[j]]++; // this is where the 0x34B6F822 error is

}

for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    C[i] +=  C[i - 1];
}

for (j = n; j >= 1; j--) {
    B[C[A[j]]] = A[j];
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1;
}


}



int main()
  {
int A[] = { 6,5,8,4,3 };
int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (A[i] > k)
        k = A[i];
}


int* B = new int[n];

int j;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    printf("%d ", B[j]);
printf("\n");

count(A, B, k, n);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Heed my advice: Use `std::vector`s.

Comment: Off by one error.  The size of `C` is `k` but you try to access the `k`th element.

Comment: All your `for` loops inside `count` access past the last element

Comment: For your sake and ours please use meaningful variable names (i.e. *not* single letter names)

Comment: Many off by one errors. `for (i = 0; i < k+1; i++) {` -> `k+1` and `for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {` -> `i <= k` both result in out of bounds access in addition to whatever may be stored in `A`

Answer (score 6):

C has k elements, with indices from 0 to k - 1. However, the max value in A is equal to k. Therefore, at some point, you are accessing C[k], which points to memory you do not own.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem in your code.

**First:** The size of `C` array is less which can store only `k` elements which start from `0` to `k-1` hence it cannot able to store maximum element of `A` array. Size of array `C` will be `int* C = new int[k+1];`

**Second:** When you are counting the frequency of `A` array in `C` that time you are running a loop from `1` to `n` instead of `0` to `n-1` which may lead to an error because size of array 'A`is '0-based` indexed. Similar error you are making while filling `B` array  in which you loop should run from `n-1` to `0`.

Here is the correct which will run perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector> 


using namespace std;

void count(int A[], int B[], int k, int n) {


int i;
int j;

int* C = new int[k+1];


for (i = 0; i < k+1; i++) {
    C[i] = 0;
}

for (j = 0; j <n; j++) {
    C[A[j]]++; //  error is removed

}




for (i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    C[i] +=  C[i - 1];
}



for (j = n-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    B[C[A[j]]-1] = A[j];
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1;
}


}



int main()
  {
int A[] = { 6,5,8,4,3 };
int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
int k = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (A[i] > k)
        k = A[i];
}


int* B = new int[n];

int j;


count(A, B, k, n);

for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    printf("%d ", B[j]);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No,look my code properly the size of `C` is now `0` to `k` not `k-1`.   `int* C = new int[k+1];`

Comment: Ah. Recommend marking that better. Add a big comment or similar to make the change obvious. That said are you certain this is the correct solution to the problem? `k` was likely selected for a reason and working past `k` may produce incorrect results. Better to crash a program due to out of bounds access than crash a plane due to undetected math error.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you are speaking that the problem will fail for large value of `k` ? . Here, `k` is the maximum value in array `A`. Please, clarify yourself.

Comment: My point is your solution prevents a crash but gives no assurances that the program is correct. It is often better to have an obvious bug than [one hiding in the shadows, waiting for an opportune moment to strike.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE)

Comment: Above code will work perfectly until elements in array `A` is small. Usually `Counting Sort` used to work when elements is small. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) is similar implementation on counting sort.